# Add optional _locale to routes

Tags: symfony

I'd like to prefix all my urls by an optional `_locale`. BTW, I'm handling `fr` and `en`.

The point is, when `_locale` is given I'll use it thanks to [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest`, if not I'll use the locale saved in the database thanks to my own listener (priority: 15) which runs immediately after the previous one.

What I've tried so far is the following:

> app/config/routing.yml

```
 entrypoint:
     resource: 'locale_prefixed_routing.yml'
     prefix: /{_locale}
```

And `locale_prefixed_routing.yml` imports bundles routings.

`/fr/url/example` works but `/url/example` does not and returns 404 page.

How do I tell symfony to use the locale in the url, if does not exist use the one in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your routes are defined like this in your **locale_prefixed_routing.yml** :

```
my_route:
    path: /
    defaults:
```

Actually routes like `/url/example` without any locale are not defined in your routing because you ask to prefix all the routes loaded in locale_prefixed_routing.yml by the locale. So it is normal to get an error when requesting such a route without locale.

You can try to make another routing file named **non_localized_routing.yml** containing the same routes except that you will use specific defaults.

Example :

```
route_example:
    path: /url/example
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /{_locale}/url/example
        permanent: true
```

Tell me if it permits you to get rid of your problem, I haven't test it yet.

Answer (score -2):

For me it sounds weird to store the locale in the database when the locale is not provided by the user. You can simply add a default one:

```
framework:
    default_locale: en
```

Comment: The issue is not related to the default locale. It is rather a route definition issue, routes without locales aren't defined. He must define them in order to specify the defaults routes with locale to use instead.